# Access value in array returned by Google Sheets API in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, google-sheets-api, google-api-php-client

I am using PHP to read and write to Google Sheets using the Google Sheets API. When I use this command:

```
$my_variable=$service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId,$range);
```

The API returns an `object(Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange)` that looks like this:

```
{
  ["collection_key":protected]=> string(6) "values" 
  ["majorDimension"]=> string(4) "ROWS"
  ["range"]=> string(9) "Sheet1!A4"
  ["values"]=> array(1)
    {
      [0]=> array(1)
      {
        [0]=> string(3) "180"
      }
    }
  ["internal_gapi_mappings":protected]=> array(0) { }
  ["modelData":protected]=> array(0) { }
  ["processed":protected]=> array(0) { }
}
```

The number I want is in the array, it's the answer (output from spreadsheet) which in this case is `"180"`.  What PHP command can I use to pluck that value from the array and `echo` / print it to the screen?

Comment: `print $my_variable->values[0][0];` looking at the object and it's returned dataset

Comment: Have you tried anything? You've dumped an object, so why not access it?

Comment: Thanks for replying Nico.  I am new to PHP so I know it is probably a basic question.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using the below statement. As far as I understand any API response will be a normal object access methodology.

```
echo $my_variable->values[0][0];
```

Let me know if you face any issues.

Hope this helps.